# Escape space in CSS

Tags: css

I am currently developing a wordpress theme. One of the plugins we are using has a `div` surrounding it with the class `widget widget_woothemes_testimonials`. I am wondering how to escape the space in the class so I can select it with CSS. How can I do this?

EDIT:

The `div` looks like so;

```
<div class="widget widget_woothemes_testimonials">
     <!--CODE-->
</div>
```

Comment: Why do want to escape the space? Just select both. `.widget.widget_woothemes_testimonials`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two classes: `widget` and `widget_woothemes_testimonials`.

You can select either class.

Answer (score 4):

You want to select only divs with BOTH classes? Is that what you're asking?

If so you'd write this selector:

```
.widget.widget_woothemes_testimonials{
}
```